# Numbers permutation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, logic, algorithms, permutations

Given $n$ numbers and $k$ positions I want the total number of permutations of these n numbers on these $k$ positions if repetition is allowed and if the following two arrangements are considered similar :

1 Two arrangements $(A$ and  $B)$ are similar if $B$ is a cyclic shift of $A$.

Example : ${2 3 1}$ is cyclic shift of ${1 2 3}$

2 Two arrangements $(A$ and $B)$ are similar if $B$ is a reversed cyclic shift of $A$.

Example : ${3 2 1 5 4}$ is reversed cyclic shift of ${1 2 3 4 5}$.

Comment: This is like say saying how many necklaces can be made by stringing $n$ beads of $k$ possible colours. Lurking in the background is an action of the dihedral group.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem#A_simplified.2C_unweighted_version).

Comment: Ya..it can be think of like that. So do you have any idea of solving it?

Comment: Can you please be specific.I dont get the link between your posted link and the problem

Comment: Regarding @Mike's observation, $n$ and $k$ seem to be swapped here.

Comment: @ccorn If u get mike explanation can u explain me a bit with a formula for the above problem along with its proof

Comment: Do you know if $n>k$, or $k\leq n$, etc.?

Comment: K can be larger or smaller than n.No such constraint

Comment: @Mike your approach is good.Please could You provide me with a formula for this problem along with its proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set of all functions $f : \{1,\ldots,k\} \to \{1,\ldots,n\}$. Each function in $X$ should be thought of as an $n$-colouring of the vertices of a regular $k$-gon.   Let $D_{2k}$ act on these functions by the rule
$$\sigma \cdot f = f \circ \sigma^{-1}.$$
The inverse is not really important. Without it you get an antiaction of $D_{2k}$ on $X$. Convince yourself that you are counting the number of orbits of this group action. From the [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem#A_simplified.2C_unweighted_version) I linked in the comments, the count is
$$ \frac{1}{2k} \sum_{\sigma \in D_{2k}} n^{c(\sigma)} $$
where $c(\sigma)$ is the number of cycles in the cycle-decomposition of $\sigma$. So, everything comes down to studying the cycle structure of the permutations in $D_{2k}$. These fall into two types: there are $k$ rotations, and $k$ reflections.

**Reflections, $k$ even**:

- For $k/2$ reflections $\sigma$, the line of symmetry does not contain any vertex of the $k$-gon. Such reflections decompose as the product of $k/2$ disjoint tranpositions, each vertex being paired with its mirror image. So, in this case, $c(\sigma) = k/2$.
- For the other $k/2$ reflections $\sigma$, the line of symmetry contains two vertices.  Such reflections have 2 fixed points and $(k-2)/2$ disjoint transpositions in their cycle structure. So, $c(\sigma) = (k-2)/2 + 2= k/2 + 1$

**Reflections, $k$ odd**

- In this case, all $k$ reflections $\sigma$ have one vertex on their line of symmetry and their cycle structure consists of 1 fixed point and $(k-1)/2$ disjoint transpositions. So $c(\sigma) = (k-1)/2 + 1 = (k+1)/2$.

**Rotations**

Let $\sigma$ be the rotation sending $1 \mapsto 2 \mapsto \cdots \mapsto k \mapsto 1$. Then all of the $k$ rotations are $\sigma^p$ where $p=1,\ldots,k$. Note that, for each rotation $\sigma^p$, all the cycles have the same size $o_p$, the order of the rotation. The order of $\sigma^p$ equals $\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(k,p)}{p}$ and so $c(\sigma^k) = k/o_p = \frac{p \cdot k}{\operatorname{lcm}(k,p)} = \operatorname{gcd}$.

**Totalling things up:**

If $k$ is even, the count is
$$ \frac{1}{2k} \left( \frac{k}{2} \cdot n^{\frac{k}{2}} + \frac{k}{2} \cdot n^{\frac{k}{2} + 1} + \sum_{p=1}^{k} n^{\operatorname{gcd}(k,p) 
} \right) $$

If $k$ is odd, the count is
$$ \frac{1}{2k} \left( k \cdot n^\frac{k+1}{2} + \sum_{p=1}^{k} n^{\operatorname{gcd}(k,p)
} \right)$$

Something to think about, can the summation be simplified? Maybe look it up in the O.I.E.S.

Comment: +1 nice answer, and I never knew of that result you link to.

Comment: I checked it for n=3 where numbers are {1,2,3} and k=4 .I think result i am getting by using above formula is still incorrect.Because the answer should be 21 as 21 such cases are possible.  These are :{1111 ,1112 ,1113 ,1122 ,1123 ,1133 ,1212 ,1213 ,1222 ,1223,  1232 ,1233 ,1313 ,1323 ,1333 ,2222 ,2223 ,2233 ,2323 ,2333 ,3333}.No other case is possible.But result according to formula give higher results.

Comment: @user3001932: Sorry I was not careful enough. The order of $\sigma^p$ should be $\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(k,p)}{p}$, not $\frac{k}{\operatorname{lcm}(k,p)}$ (which isn't even usually an integer).

Comment: Now the formula gives 21 when $k=4,n=3$ which matches your list.

Comment: hmm..Ya..its perfect now..Really appreciable effort.Thanx

Comment: No prob. I made one more cosmetic tweak. Of course $\frac{pk}{lcm(p,k)}$ just equals $gcd(p,k)$. Regards.

Comment: Oh..Ya..its a good reduction..:)